# iPhone 4S is unable to handle full resolution from AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, photo, avcapturesession

I've been developing my project on iPhone 4S and the iPhone5. In my project, after the picture is taken, I crop it and then resize the image to apply photo filters. The iPhone 5 seems to handle this very well however on the iPhone 4S, it seems to crash at different points during the picture taking process. I checked to see if there we're any memory leaks that I may have missed. Here is the code below:

```
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
 {

     [captureSession stopRunning];

     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

After this, I automatically detect the orientation of the picture taken and rotate the picture so that it is always upright.

After this, I crop the image into a square using [NYXImagesKit](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit)

```
     float filteringSquareRatio = 307.0/320.0;
     UIImage *cropped = [newImage cropToSize:CGSizeMake(filteringSquareRatio * newImage.size.width, filteringSquareRatio * newImage.size.width) usingMode:NYXCropModeCenter];
```

Lastly, I resize the image using [MGImageUtilities](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities)

```
    UIImage *resized = [cropped imageScaledToFitSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320)];
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm currently using AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto because I would like to save the original high resolution photo on the device and send the cropped and resized version to the server. I don't want to use any of the video presets because the camera is zoomed in. What can be causing the crashing?

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't able to find a solution to this (I see this problem too), you could perhaps detect the 4s and use the "high" preset instead which has lower resolution.